# Prevent verbose output undumping from mysqldump

Tags: mysql, performance, verbose

I've dumped a table on a remote server from one database (MySQL 5.5) to a file. It took the server about 2 seconds to perform the operation. Now I'm trying to undump data from the file into another DB (same version) on the server.

The server outputs the data being processed on the screen in spite of the fact I didn't specify --verbose parameter. How can I prevent the output?

It takes the server some 10 minutes to perform the operation. Is that time acceptable or can I make it much faster? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: *"The server outputs the data being processed on the screen"*  You are using a command incorrectly if this appears to be happening, because there should not be a way to make it happen at all -- verbose or not.  What is the command you are using to load the data?

Comment: It's "mysqldump -u username -p database_name < mydump.sql".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading (undumping) is via the `mysql` commandline tool:

```
mysql  -u user  -p  dbname  < mydump.sql
```